# Find if element exists in N-dimensional array

Tags: list-manipulation, searching

I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of finding whether an element exists in an N-dimensional array. The way I would do it is:

```
 inArrayQ[a_,el_] := If[Length@Position[a,x_/;x==el]==0,False,True];
```

But this seems rather cumbersome. I am surprised there is no built-in Mathematica function that does this, but if not, is there a better way to write such a function?

Comment: check out `MemberQ`

Comment: D'oh, if only the documentation search was better...thanks.

Comment: @Guillochon If you search for `MemberQ` you get the answer right away ;)

Comment: @Guillochon You can also use `Position` to determine where the element is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to have any more open, unanswered questions

Check out [`MemberQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MemberQ.html), you should find all information there.